# Blender rendering blank frames

Tags: rendering, animation

[image]
[image]
I just did a render overnight, of a scene and it did fine. I made some adjustments to the timing of some shots to slow down and smooth the movement of the camera. I also increased the frame rate to 30fps and changed the bit depth from 8 to 16. I decreased the frame steps from 1 to 0 and decreased the compression to 0, to try and get better quality because the render looked jumpy around the corners of the walls / rooms. When I went to render again, it is rendering blank frames and the frame counter is going fast as if it's just counting frames but not rendering them. Any ideas? I tried putting everything back the way it was, but it still renders blank frames. I have also made sure the camera is not behind anything. I checked the render sequence in the output folder and none of the frames have images on them. I also tried rendering a single frame and it does the same thing.

Comment: "decreased the frame steps from 1 to 0"  is the problem I'd expect, that says there is no frame increment during rendering. Set it back to '1' or greater.  I'd say it's a bug that it allows you to set it below '1'.

Comment: "I tried putting everything back the way it was, but it still renders blank frames.". A higher number in frame steps skips more frames. That also wouldn't effect rendering a single frame.

Comment: I started a new blend file, appended everything from my old scene into it, and everything works fine even after changing everything to the new settings.

Comment: My favorite saying: "When in doubt, reboot!"

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. I don't know what caused it, but I deleted some frames in the animation from about the time that I had changed settings and was looking around the model in camera, and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you turned off your lights in render mode. This may result in a blank scene. Just click on the camera icons next to the lights to turn them back on.

[image]

Comment: I already found out what was wrong. I changed some settings while I was adding key frames in animation. I went back and deleted those from about the time I made the changes, and everything went back normal. I didn't have anything hidden and that would give a solid gray or black background, not a checkerboard pattern. I always check the basics before I post questions on here.